# Multiple columns/values with index/match in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I need to get multiple columns/rows/values from one tables that matches some conditions in excel.

This is an example table .

[image: Table]

I need to pull only values that matches n in H column.

I use this formula, and got correct result but only first match in a table.i need to populate all rows.

=INDEX(G13:H21,MATCH($C$29,H13:H21,0),{1,2})

Appreciate help

Comment: Use a filter.  Either the auto or advanced filters should do what you describe.

Comment: Filter doesn't work for me in this case.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain your problem better, and why a filter doesn't work, you can get a more useful suggestion.  To help us help you better, suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: I think I was very clear about my post. I tried to use filters from various forums but my data resides in imported CSV that changes every day. If you give me an example how do you mean to accomplish that, I can try . Ty

Comment: You never mentioned that the data source was CSV! What version of Excel?

Comment: It is 2016.....

Comment: Exactly how are you getting the data from the CSV file into Excel

Comment: I used Data tab in excel and "from text/csv" option. It is a connection if it helps.

Comment: My only problem with my existing formula is I only get first match/result.

Comment: That is how that works.  When you do your csv import, are you seeing the legacy wizard or the new wizard built into Get & Transform?

Comment: I believe it is a new one. I have an option "transform data" at the bottom. It is a different from what I have seen before in earlier versions of excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you write that a filter does not work in your case.

[image]

After you select the `from text/csv` option, at the next screen, select `Edit`.

[image]

Select to Use First Row as Headers

Then, from the dropdown arrow for column 2, you can select the Filter option, and check the `n` box only.

You will now have a recorded query that you can use for subsequent iterations of the CSV file.

If you need to filter for multiple values, you can import the CSV without filtering, then execute multiple queries against the originally imported data.

**EDIT:** *If you choose this method, you should update the external connection query first.  Then a `Refresh All` will update the dependent queries. You could do this by selecting `Refresh on Workbook Open` just for that query; or selecting it for none of them, but doing a refresh for that external query upon Workbook Open.*

Other options:

- Duplicate the table and have different auto or advanced filters on each iteration.
- you could use a formula.  One problem is that you would have to adjust your formula after each import if the range to be examined is different. With your data table in `A1:B9`, and your filter value in G1, a formula might look like:

---

```
Product:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet5!$A$2:$B$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((Sheet5!$B$2:$B$9=$G$1)*ROW(Sheet5!$A$2:$B$9))),ROWS($1:1))-ROW(Sheet5!$A$1:$B$1),1),"")

Validity: =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet5!$A$2:$B$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((Sheet5!$B$2:$B$9=$G$1)*ROW(Sheet5!$A$2:$B$9))),ROWS($1:1))-ROW(Sheet5!$A$1:$B$1),2),"")
```

Then fill down as far as needed

Comment: If I filter CSV, I will loose some data that are used for other queries. I will have to have 5-8 different queries from the same CSV.

Comment: @Sasa Having multiple queries is not a problem.  To avoid reading the csv file multiple times (time consuming), read it once without filtering, then do multiple queries on that file to create the different filters you require.

Comment: Ron, thank you for you help. Appreciate it. How to perform filtering after importing CSV. Not that I need to have filtered data in a separate sheet.

Comment: Go to the same Data tab but, instead of `From Text/CSV`, select `From Table/Range` with your import table selected.  Or you can just duplicate the original table and set up multiple advanced filters.

Comment: Hm. I wasn't aware of  import from table/range option. In this case I actually create query as I can see? That means I must refresh data to get up to date data. This might work, I must test it. Regarding second option. If I duplicate original table, what will happen when new CSV is imported? Duplicated data will have different data then newly imported CSV.

Comment: @Sasa It depends on how you duplicate it.  If you import to the same location (by refreshing the Query), and you use cell references instead of copy/paste, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Sasa You'd have a similar problem using formulas, so far as ensuring the formulas are obtaining data from the required source.

Comment: Ron, thank you so much! I think first solution that your proposed will work for me (import table/range).

Comment: @Sasa Also, if your using the first solution, see my Edit to avoid getting the tables "out of sync"

Comment: Ron, I tried briefly with Refresh All and it worked. Ty